# How to Use @JsonProperty With Lombok?

Tags: java, json, lombok

Suppose we have a json response that we want to map it to our java class.

```
{
    "access_token": "abcdefg..."
}
```

I had a data class that mapped `access_token` field in the json to `accessToken` field in the code. I used to use `@JsonProperty` annotation on getters and setters.

```
private String accessToken;

@JsonProperty("accessToken")
public String getAccessToken() {
    return accessToken;
}

@JsonProperty("access_token")
public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
    this.accessToken = accessToken;
}
```

Then I decided to use Lombok annotations `@Getter` and `@Setter`. Since I do not have a getter and setter in my code, how can I map `access_token` field in the json to `accessToken` field in the code with Lombok annotations?

My code is like this right now and as you can expect, it cannot map the fields.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Token {
    private String accessToken;
}
```

I do not want to name my variable to `access_token` because I also return access token as a json response and I want it to appear as `accessToken` in my json response.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a way to do it.

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Token {
    @Setter(onMethod = @__(@JsonSetter(value = "access_token"))) 
    @Getter(onMethod = @__(@JsonGetter(value = "accessToken"))) 
    private String accessToken;
}
```

Another solution is to use `@JsonAlias` annotation.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Token {
    @JsonAlias("access_token"))) 
    private String accessToken;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No need for all this, you can simply annotate your field with @JsonProperty. Spring will still use the getters for serialization.

```
@Data
public class Token {
   @JsonProperty("access_token")
   private String accessToken;
}
```